# Перемножить числа, переданные в строке, перечисленные через запятую (python)

Tags: python

```
def multiply_nums(input_string):
    """
    Перемножить числа, переданные в строке, перечисленные через запятую.
   
    """
    mul = str(0)
    input_string.split(sep=',')
    for x in range(0, len(input_string)):
      mul *= input_string[x]
    return mul
```

Comment: вы хотели чем-то похвастаться или задать какой-то вопрос? Кстати, умножая 0 на что угодно вы ничего кроме 0 не получите. А умножая строку на что угодно вы не получите число.

Comment: Задать вопрос. У меня такая ошибка TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'.

Comment: Извиняюсь, да перепутала, но даже если я укажу mul = 1, выдает туже ошибку. Не могу понять, как перемножить числа между собой, заданные в строке

Comment: @user543688 "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'" прочитайте сам перевод ошибки, вы пытаетесь выполнить операцию число*строка

Comment: @Аске можете, пожалуйста, подсказать как перемножить числа между собой, заданные в строке

Comment: @user543688 задача немного не понятная, но ниже скину ответ

Comment: `math.prod(map(int, input_string.split(',')))`.

Comment: @Аске Там ещё хуже всё - идёт попытка перемножить строку на строку )

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Моё решение по вопросу

```
def multiply_nums(input_string):
    """
    Перемножить числа, переданные в строке, перечисленные через запятую.
   
    """

    numbers = input_string.split(',')
    mul = int(numbers[0])
    for x in range(1, len(numbers)):
      number = numbers[x]
      mul *= int(number)
    return mul

print(multiply_nums('5,7,1,6,4'))
```

Comment: И почему же минус репутация? Я вроде правильно решил задачу, напишите свои претензии

Comment: возможно причина описана где-то здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Аске спасибо вам большое за помощь

Answer (score 2):

```
def multiply_nums(s: str) -> int:
    s = map(int, s.split(','))
    mul = 1
    for i in s:
        mul *= i

    return mul
```

Во-первых, строка на строку не умножается, а вы делаете именно это, потому что хоть и разделив строку по запятым, элементы в списке все еще имеют строковый тип данных. Надо понимать, что **2 + 2 != '2' + '2'**
Во-вторых, если вы ставите начальным числом 0, то результата в умножении это не даст. Если бы было сложение, то да, начинаем с 0, если нет доп. условий.
А да, вы таким образом и не разделили список, вы получили ту же строку с пробелами и запятыми и занимаетесь перебором строки. Чтобы разделить - нужно присвоить результат работы split, например так:

```
input_string = input_string.split(sep=',')
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь